# Elasticsearch: Search in an array of JSONs

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm using Elasticsearch with the python library and I have a problem using the search query when the object become a little bit complex. I have objects build like that in my index:

```
{
   "id" : 120,
   "name": bob,
   "shared_status": {
       "post_id": 123456789,
       "text": "This is a sample",
       "urls" : [
           {
              "url": "http://test.1.com",
              "displayed_url": "test.1.com" 
           },
           {
              "url": "http://blabla.com",
              "displayed_url": "blabla.com" 
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Now I want to do a query that will return me this document only if in one of the displayed URL's a substring "test" and there is a field "text" in the main document. So I did this query:

```
{
   "query": {
       "bool": {
           "must": [
                    {"exists": {"field": "text"}}
                   ]
           }
        }
   }
}
```

But I don't know what query to add for the part: `one of the displayed URL's a substring "test"`

Is that posssible? How does the iteration on the list works?

Comment: It is possible. Please provide output of  _mapping : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Comment: The question is about query elasticsearch not iterate on a JSON

Comment: @rahulroc I simplified the situation using a fake example but my application is about tweets from the API twitter. And there is no mapping defined for those fields in my mapping.

Comment: @mel As you didn't provide explicit mapping, ES assumes some mapping types based on input data, more details in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't define an explicit mapping for your schema, elasticsearch creates a default mapping based on the data input.

- `urls` will be of type [object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html)
- `displayed_url` will be of type string and using [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)

As you don't need any association between `url` and `displayed_url`, the current schema will work fine.

You can use a [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) for full text match

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "text"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "urls.displayed_url": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```